# How not to expose a public interface in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

In my project [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), I model SQL queries with a complex data structure. All components of a query implement

```
public interface QueryPart {
  int bind(java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt);
  int bind(java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt, int initialIndex);
  SQLDialect getDialect();
  String toSQLDeclaration();
  String toSQLDeclaration(boolean inlineParameters);
  String toSQLReference();
  String toSQLReference(boolean inlineParameters);
}
```

This interface's methods are used internally by all packages of the library to construct and execute SQL. They should not be invoked directly from client code. For that purpose, I have added

```
public interface QueryPartProvider {
  QueryPart getQueryPart();
}
```

Which is the only publicly exposed interface. An example of an actual query part is:

```
public interface Table extends QueryPartProvider {}
class TableImpl implements QueryPart, Table {}
```

As you can see, the QueryPart methods can only be accessed via `Table.getQueryPart().toSQLDeclaration()`, etc.

My design helps discouraging direct access to QueryPart methods, but cannot completely hide it. My question is: **Can anyone tell me a good design pattern to achieve this goal?**

Note: The simplest but not very nice solution would be to cast all objects to QueryPart, e.g. `((QueryPart) table).toSQLDeclaration()`

Comment: Why do you add a 'getQueryPart' method if you like to hide it?

Comment: You can try hide objects that implements this interface. Is this what you need?

Comment: @Arne: I want to hide it from client code, but expose it to the library. @Stas: Objects implementing the interface are package private (see TableImpl). Those objects are exposed via interfaces (see Table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After implementing something similar to what *sfussenegger* suggested, I came up with an even better solution involving the *Adapter design pattern*. This is the general outline:

```
/**
 * Objects providing an internal API implement this interface
 */
public interface Adapter {

  /**
   * Dynamically expose an (publicly unknown) internal API. 
   */
  <T> T internalAPI(Class<T> internalType) throws ClassCastException;
}
```

This adapter type is the only fact exposed to the public about anything internal. Only package private implementation methods know about the possible arguments to this method (and those hackers that really want to actually use the internal API for workarounds, extensions, etc).

```
/**
 * This type contains the public API for a QueryPart
 */
public interface QueryPart extends Adapter {
// [...]
}

/**
 * This type contains the internal API for a QueryPart
 */
public interface QueryPartInternal extends QueryPart {
// [...]
}
```

The above QueryPart and QueryPartInternal are related. This fact is known to public but no public class / type extends QueryPartInternal. Only the following package-private class and its gazillion subclasses do:

```
/**
 * This class is the base class for all QueryParts.
 * It is package private and thus doesn't expose anything
 */
abstract class AbstractQueryPart implements QueryPartInternal {
  // [...]

  /**
   * For other package private implementation methods
   */
  @Override
  public final <T> internalAPI(Class<T> internalType) {
    return internalType.cast(this);
  }

  /**
   * Convenience method for subclasses heavily using the
   * internal API
   */
  protected final QueryPartInternal internal(QueryPart part) {
    return part.internalAPI(QueryPartInternal.class);
  }
  // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All methods of an interface are always public, so there is no way for you to have access to something which is not accessible to your library clients as well.
Maybe you could achieve what you want using an abstract class for `Table`, and the `getQueryPart()` method as package protected. I'm not sure however that I would want to do that, instead of a cast from `Table` to `TableImpl`.

Comment: Abstract classes are not the best way to go in Java as no multiple inheritance is allowed. Many implementations of QueryPart extend some other classes...

Comment: Using an Abstract class and making the abstract methods protected worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explain why you'd like to do that? The only reason I can see is to make it impossible to implement the interface for a user of your library.

I don't think that's a good approach. Simply add some Javadoc and explain why it doesn't make sense to implement it. But finally, leave it to the user whether there's a valid reason to create a custom implementation. It's always difficult to foresee each and every use case.

If somebody gots stuck with his approach it's certainly not your fault - he can't say he hasn't been warned :)

To give an example, that's what you can find all over Apache Wicket's source code:

```
/**
 * THIS IS WICKET INTERNAL ONLY. DO NOT USE IT.
 * 
 * Traverses all behaviors and calls ...
 */
```

EDIT:
just another though: you could try this, although I'd still discourage it - don't say you haven't been warned ;)

```
public interface ExposedInterface {
  void foo();
}

// only default visibility
interface InternalInterface extends ExposedInterface {
  // nothing here
}

// and here some methods
ExposedInterface get(); // user can use it

void set(InternalInterface obj); // user is out of luck here
```

Comment: As I said, I need the interface's methods internally in the library. I don't want the user to implement this interface. But if the public API does not implement the interface in some way, then library code would need to class cast things all the time. See the example with the TableImpl and Table

Comment: Ah now that edit changes some things. Good point about the Javadoc. I have already done that (not in the above example) :-) Glad to see that the Wicket folks had the same idea.

Comment: @lukas I've added some more thoughts. "I don't want the user to implement this interface" could be explained as "I don't think the user will ever have to implement this interface", right?

Comment: Yeah. The user will never have to implement this interface

Comment: @Lukas ok, here's one last try

Comment: Hehe, ok, well that's quite a workaround. I can see you're creative :-) But I think, the Javadoc will do for now. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Hi @sfussenegger. You might be interested in my updated answer. I came up (a bit late but still) with a pretty good solution to this problem...